# C#: Override generic method using class generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Why is this not possible?

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract T f<T>();
}

class B<T> : A
{
    public override T f()
    {
        return default (T);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
does not implement inherited abstract member 'A.f<T>()'
no suitable method found to override
```

I know that the signature must be same, but from my point of view I see no reason what could possibly be wrong that this is forbidden.
Also I know that another solution is to make `A` generic, rather than its method, but it is not suitable for me for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` does not fulfil the contract of `A`.

`A` allows `f` to be called with any type parameter to return that type. `B` doesn't allow `f` to be called with a type parameter, and just returns the type of `B`'s type parameter.

For example, say you had a `B<int>` and cast it to an `A` (which should be possible as it inherits from it). Then you called `f<bool>()` on it (which should be possible as it's an `A`). What then? The underlying `B<int>` doesn't have a method to call.

```
B b = new B<int>();
// This is legal as B inherits from A
A a = b;
// This is a legal call, but how does b handle it?
bool result = a.f<bool>();
```

Comment: >B only allows f to be called with B's type parameter
B does not have a generic method `f` at all so B doesn't even allow f to be called with B's type paramter

Comment: Great answer... I think this explains the reason in the best way.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible because those methods have different signatures. `A.f` is generic method and `B.f` is not (it merely uses class generic argument).

You can see this form caller perspective:

```
A variableA = new A();
variableA.f<int>();

B<int> variableB = new B<int>();
variableB.f();
```

Comment: I know signature is different. But isn't it same if I specify the generic parameter when creating instead of during invoking the method?
I see it this way: T A.f() == T B.f() - both methods takes same parameters, and returns same type, so what problem do I miss?

Comment: No it is not. You can easily declare generic class that contains generic method. You are disputing how C# is designed you have two choices accept it or change language.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your code

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract T f<T>();
}

class B<T> : A
{
    public override T f()
    {
        return default (T);
    }
}
```

what do you expect to be called in the below code

```
public void Foo(A myObj) {
    myObj.f<DateTime>();
}
Foo(new B<int>());
```

There's no implementation for that method though the type contract (the abstract class A) clearly states that you need an implementation. So you can either implement or change the contract to use a type argument at the class level

```
abstract class A<T>
{
    public abstract T f();
}

class B<T> : A<T>
{
    public override T f()
    {
        return default (T);
    }
}
```

does compile however it also limits f of course

Comment: My idea is 

    A myObj = new B<int>();
    myObj.f();
Note missing `DateTime` from calling `f`. I want to say during creation, this class uses T as generic parameters for all its functions.

Comment: @Zoka you're right "_for all its functions_". But `f<T>` is the function of the base class and derived class type parameter has no power over it. It's base class method's type parameter - method level, not class.

Comment: Now... last example of Rune FS here: I can name generic parameter same name for class and overrides and it really compiles, with warning - but what does it do? My guess is it just hide the class parameter from using inside the overriden method, right?

Comment: @Zoka it's the same, as if you had different names, i.e. you still may specify any type parameter while calling `f<anything>();` and it'll use the specified by the call one, not the class type parameter.

Comment: @Konstantin: I thought so.

Comment: @Zoka I've update the example to (hopefully) make it more clear why you're argumentation does not hold. The type system allows you to use any A as a parameter to the above method (and since B derives from A any B is also an A). The compiler needs to be able to guarantee that you can pass a B as an argument to that method and to be able to do that it needs to guarantee that B.f<DateTime>() is valid

Comment: @Rune FS: Thanks +1 for that example as this is the answer to my question (but Rawling was quicker :-))

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you intend to do:

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract T f<T>();
}

class B<U> : A
{
    public override T f<T>() //also needs to have a generic type parameter
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public U f()
    {
        return f<U>();
    }
}
```

The generic method type parameter and the generic class type parameter (here `T` and `U`) have no straightforward connection, i.e. `T` is not restricted to be `U` (or something) in the base class and you cannot change this restriction in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract T f<T>();
}

class B<T> : A
{
    public override T f<T>()
    {
        return default (T);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the solution, I want to know WHY?

Comment: this is one right way, it's quastion same as "i can't override method `public abstract void Func()` as `public override bool Func(int digit)` why?" signature is not match